# Java REST api vs Django REST api for ML

Tags: java, python, django, tensorflow

It's been trivial thing for me!, and bugging me for over a 2 weeks.

My Project Contains MVC in Java - Spring+Hibernate.

I've been using Java for more than 4 years, so far it's good, but recent Machine learning bothering me so much because i just want to restart my 4 year old project in Machine Learning(It's best thing for my project, And i can't reinvent algorithm to match for my project).

I read lot about Machine learning, I was so keen at Google TensorFlow, Sadly i can't use it in Java as i know, The API by google is not ready for Java.On the other hand i read about DL4J, it's seems okay but i have to explore it.

On the Python side TensorFlow works flawless and SciKit too, but i'm new to Python Django REST framework. I'll quickly may catch up DRF. And it's seems that DRF is so light weight and pretty great without like spring annotation and hibernate annotation and too many stupid things.

But one thing bothering so much! is that should i stick to Java with DL4J or switch it to Python DRF?

Please suggest me which track should i choose?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on your need. If the Java project has lots of code(as its 4 years of old), then I would suggest to keep it as it is and use it as data source, and use python app with ML to consume it.

Comment: Thought of refactoring it python, since ML will eliminate lot buggy codes too.

Comment: depends on your time and knowledge in python/django/drf. I would say if you only need api without DB support and have no prior knowledge in python/django, then you can look into [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: if requires rapid development django go with python, since you already know thesame concepts in java its not hard to get it done